# How to bring out the request-promise result to the outside scope?

Tags: node.js

How to bring out the request-promise result to the outside scope?

I don't know why my bot echo 10 instead of 100.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrtvu.png)

This is the result I tried to get with await
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXEUG.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend reading a bit more about promises and async/await in JavaScript, but to answer your question:

Your `getAreaWeather()` function is an `async` function, so you don't need to use an ES6 promise chain (`.then()` and `.catch()`), and you need to actually make sure your `rp()` promise resolves before you return anything. Your current function is setting `abc` to 10, then starting the request in `rp()`, but it immediately returns `abc` (which still equals 10 because the request hasn't finished yet)

This is just an example of how to fix the promises; I don't know if there are any issues with the HTML parsing.

```
async function getAreaWeather() {
  var abc = 10;
  var weathers = [];
  var options = {/*what you have in your screenshot*/};

  try {
    // Wait for the rp() promise to resolve
    var $ = await rp(options);

    // Use $ however you want...

    abc = 100;

    return abc;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  // You could also return abc here if you want, but be aware it'll still equal 10 if the rp() throws an error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, change `rp().then...` to `await rp().then..`. Js is asynchronous. While the rp() function runs, it takes some time. So, the code below it gets executed in that time.Hence, value of abc is never changed from inside the rp() function.

Comment: Thank you so much.